# Error when using filter function: object 'restaurant' not found

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting to restrict the `fastfood` dataset from the `openintro` package to only two restaurants, Taco Bell and Burger King. This is the code I am using

```
dataset <- filter(fastfood, restaurant %in% c("Taco Bell", "Burger King"))
```

and this is the error I receive:

```
Error in restaurant %in% c("Taco Bell", "Burger King") : 
  object 'restaurant' not found
```

Yet I am able to see all restaurants using `fastfood$restaurant`

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: There is a `filter` function in dplyr and also one in the base of R.  Type `filter` into the R console and the last line of the output will show which one is being used.  If it is the one in stats then specify `dplyr::filter`.   If that is not the problem check whether `restaurant` is a column in `fastfood`.

Comment: Just tried `dplyr::filter` like @G.Grothendieck says and it worked.

Comment: We need to load the dplyr first. `library(dplyr)`, then `stats::filter` gets masked, and you don't need to use `dplyr::`.

Comment: dplyr::filter worked, thank you everyone for the help